# Resource quota management in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I need recommendation regarding resource quota management in openshift. We have enable resource quota at project level. Assigned certain amount of cpu, memory and also configured limit ranges. But due this resource quota we have a strange situation.

For example:

For one project we assigned 1 vcpu and 1 gb ram as request and 2vcpu and 2gb ram as limit. Their pod is running fine. But when they do rolling deployment, their new pod will not come up because of resource quota limit. Because deployment pod is also taking 1 cpu request and new pod requires 1 cpu request. 
So could anyone tell how to avoid this situation? How can we configure quotas so that developers will not have issue while rolling deployment.  I understand during rolling deployment it requires same amount of resources as previous pod but developers are not happy with deployment pod taking resources from their quota as it should be coming from the openshift platform.

thanks,
Santosh

Comment: If this is development, have them change the deployment strategy to Recreate. https://cookbook.openshift.org/application-lifecycle-management/how-can-i-change-the-deployment-strategy-being-used.html

Comment: Hi Graham, this is for production deployments.

Comment: For a production system then you need to realise that by switching to Recreate deployment strategy that you loose the ability to have zero downtime deployments. This is because the existing application is shutdown first before starting new deployment. If you need zero down time deployment, you need to provide extra quota equal to what is required by number of extra pods created during a rolling deployment.

Comment: Hi Graham, so developers should take account of deployment/build pods also during rolling deployment. So in this case they should use atleast 3 cpu's? please correct me.

Comment: Yes and similarly they need to allow for the extra memory.